# Why did Agent Coulson hand Thor over to Selvig?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor

In [*Thor*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800369/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), after Thor's failed attempt to retrieve Mjollnir from the S.H.I.E.L.D. compound, he gets taken into custody.  A little while later, Erik Selvig shows up, asking Agent Coulson to release him into his custody.

As Coulson is questioning him, he quickly finds plenty of evidence that Selvig is lying through his teeth about Thor's identity and Dr. Selvig's relationship with the prisoner, and Selvig is someone that Coulson already knows, and has butted heads with in the past over S.H.I.E.L.D.'s decision to confiscate his protege's research and equipment.

And yet, Coulson hands Thor over into Selvig's custody, with only an offhand order to one of his agents to "follow them," which never seems to be followed up on.  What's going on there?

Comment: That was a bit strange indeed. I thought he might just want to bring some more action into the situation and watch what *Thor* and *Selvig* are gonna do now, since he maybe realized that *Thor*'s detention won't bring him more answers than letting him do whatever he wants. He maybe also guessed that *Thor* at least wasn't on the wrong side and was just curious to see what happens. But good question.

Comment: I remember that there actually _were_ agents watching Thor and his human friends. When Thor's Asgardian friends come into town they can be seen on a rooftop, calling HQ to inform them about _"Xena, Jackie Chan, and Robin Hood"_.

Answer (score 10):

> And yet, Coulson hands Thor over into Selvig's custody, with only an
>   offhand order to one of his agents to "follow them," which never seems
>   to be followed up on. What's going on there?

**They are indeed following him**, that's why they saw his friends:

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcif323T_qo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcif323T_qo)

And right after that, the [destroyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destroyer_%28Thor%29) arrived.

So they were checking on Thor, but then all those other important events happened.